# Get availability zone of an Instance in an ASG with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using Cloudformation to launch my instance, I am using ASG just to make sure I have a healthy Instance, so I am using EBS volume in case one instance goes down it can be used for the new one.
The problem I am facing is there is no way to know the availability of instance with cloud formation so I can launch an EBS resource in that zone.

Comment: You usually define your EBS volumes in launch or template configuration for asg. Shouldn't need to define them independently.

Comment: Are you saying that you wish to reattach an Amazon EBS volume to any new instance that is launched by Auto Scaling? What are you keeping on the volume? Is there a way you can avoid using it (eg storing data in a database)?

Comment: It is a time-series database, It keep monitorng data

Comment: @Marcin I know, but i want to remount my EBS for new instances

Comment: Can you set your ASG for one zone only, or use something like EFS to keep shared data instead of EBS?